# Recycling a color palette in Gnuplot

Tags: colors, gnuplot, palette

I need to construct  a discrete palette color with only a few colors, say:

```
set palette defined (0 'red', 1 'red', 1 'green',\ 
                     2 'green', 2 'blue', 3 'blue',\
                     3 'yellow', 4 'yellow')
```

which will be applied a specific number of times to a unique matrix data-file, i.e., by recycling the palette. Suppose the matrix data-file ranges integers data from 0 up to 16. The palette will be applied four times: first, for data in `[0:4]`; second, for `[4:8]`, third, for `[8:12]` and fourth, for `[12:16]`. The final result I expect is a heat map (2D image) with four colors.

I have tried the following palette:

```
set palette defined ( (k%4==0)'red',   (k%4==1)'red',\
                      (k%4==1)'green', (k%4==2)'green',\
                      (k%4==2)'blue',  (k%4==3)'blue',\
                      (k%4==3)'yellow',(k%4==4)'yellow' )
```

where 'k' is the element of matrix data-file. My problem is to define 'k'.
Of course, it can be done by some coding on the data-file but I will lose original information.

Is there any way to define such "recycling palette"?

Comment: Can you clarify your question and provide data/example of what you've tried so far? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for reference.

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the palette the way you have it and apply the cyclic repeat at the stage of data input. Original command:

```
set cbrange [0:4]
set view map
splot $data matrix using 1:2:3 with image
```

Data value filtered to cycle through palette mapped to [0:4]

```
splot $data matrix using 1:2:(floor($3)%4) with image
```

Comment: Dear @Ethan, your sugestion almost works! I did a small modification:

`splot $data matrix u 1:2:(floor($3)%4==0? 4: floor($3)%4) with image`

Now, when the data value is multiple of 4 it is filtered as 4.
Thank you!